# Android - Button at the end of ScrollView not visible

Tags: android-studio, button, scrollview, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

I have added a button at the end of a ScrollView layout, inside it is a Constraint Layout. Both are inside a Relative layout. However, upon scrolling,  the button does not show up on my device. It's stuck at the bottom of the layout and cannot get up. I have tried everything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.BachelorDetailActivity"
    android:id="@+id/layout_fragment_studyplan">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/h1_studyplan"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/h1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/title_studyplan"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_primary"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_default"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_default"/>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/p_studyplan"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/h1_studyplan"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    android:text="@string/list_studyplan"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_huge"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_default"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_default"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/margin_short"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_contact_study"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/p_studyplan"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/button"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="500dp"
                    android:text="@string/contact_guide"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/color_primary"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the button to slide up the screen by `500dp` by setting `android:layout_marginBottom="500dp"` as the button's bottom margin, you will also need to specify a bottom constraint for the button.

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Margins apply only when there is a constraint in effect for the direction of the margin.